# How to use xpath boolean to check that element is empty in Conditional Goto (SoapUI)

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I successfully use boolean to check for not empty condition (see screenshot, and more specifically `"boolean(//planId[1])"` expression), but it's the opposite that I want to do (i.e., go to CreatePID when value is empty. How do I change to xpath to accomplish this? Thanks for any reply!

[image]

Comment: Has your question been answered?  If so, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) the answer you've found to be most helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath to test for the absence a `planId` element:

```
not(//planId)
```

Note that this is different than checking for the presence of an empty `planId`, which this XPath would do:

```
//planId[not(*)]
```